# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting an

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] jquery.js:3855

It seems i have included almost all the dependencies but still i am getting an error 
app.js

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'app.controllers'])
 
 .config(function($stateProvide, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
    url : "/home",
    templateUrl : "views/home.html",
    controller : "HomeCtrl"
   })

   .state('details', {
    url : "/details",
    templateUrl : "views/details.html",
    controller : "DetailsCtrl"
   })

   .state('about', {
    url : "/about",
    templateUrl : "views/about.html",
    controller : "AboutCtrl"
   })

   .$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
```

My controller file app.controllers.js

```js
angular.module('app.controllers',[])
 
 .controller('HomeCtrl',function($scope){
  console.log("In home ctrl");
  $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';
 })

 .controller('DetailsCtrl',function($scope){
  console.log("In details ctrl");
 })

 .controller('AboutCtrl',function($scope){
  console.log("In about ctrl");
 })
```

My index Page

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ui-router/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
     <div class="well">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" ui-sref="home">
         Home 
        </button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4 text-center" ui-sref="details">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info">
         Details
        </button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info" ui-sref="about">
         About
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-view>
      {{message}}
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error Stack

```js
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=TypeError%3A…0(http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8887%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A1)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:40:222
    at q (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:319)
    at cb (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:43:336)
    at c (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:20:390)
    at Bc (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:21:179)
    at fe (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:20:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/angular/angular.min.js:317:386)
    at mightThrow (http://127.0.0.1:8887/libs/jquery/jquery.js:3570:29)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the controllers be included before app so when you inject `app.controllers` it would actually exists?

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in config function dependency name.

```
$stateProvide
```

Should be

```
$stateProvider
```

Also you should use `ui-view` on the html instead on `ng-view`

```
.$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Should be

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); // removed. From the start
```

Comment: still the error is there after correcting the typos you pointed out

Comment: How about a semi-colon at the end of your .js files ?

Comment: @ChristianBonato yes that was the problem.

Comment: @VikramPrasad how come that solved your issue, the problem was you had `.` before $urlRouterProvider, check my last edit

Comment: @VikramPrasad can you please check with updated answer